# How to reference a dictionary through a string variable?

Tags: c#

I've got a method that takes in a string argument that has the value of a dictionary name, how would I go about using that string variable to reference the dictionary?

```
static void Info(string option, string obj)
{
    var newDict = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"Test", 0},
        {"Test2", 1)
    };
}
```

The variable 'obj' would have the value "newDict".

Comment: What do you mean with "reference the dictionary"? Do you want to look up a value to a key with said string being the key?

Comment: *"The variable 'obj' would have the value "newDict""* - but why? There is no other dictionary in that method. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I only took a snippet of my code - I've got around 5 dictionaries in total. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have to get it as a string. I would just check if the string value is equal to the name of the dictionary. simple as that. check for every known dictionary if its name matches the one you got in the string, then return that dictionary. perhaps put them all in an array or a list if there are more than a few of them.

Hope I helped, and let me know if it doesn't work for some reason

Good luck ;)

Comment: That's what I considered doing but wanted to see if there was an easier way of doing it. I'll probably just stick with this then, thanks!